# Share folder in onedrive pro via csom

Tags: c#, onedrive, csom

I create a folder using this code :

```
       context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, password);
        //login in to SharePoint online
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        //OneDrive is acctually a Document list
        List docs = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        context.Web.Folders.Add("https://xxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/xx_xx-xx_xx/Documents/myforder1");
        context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Everything work fine

Now i want to share this folder.

Does anyone know how to share a folder in onedrive using csom in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to share List Item using CSOM

The following method could be used for sharing a `List Item` object:

```
public static void ShareListItem(ListItem listItem,Principal principal,string permissionLevelName)
{
   var ctx = listItem.Context as ClientContext;
   var roleDefinition = ctx.Site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByName(permissionLevelName);
   listItem.BreakRoleInheritance(true, false);
   var roleBindings = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(ctx) {roleDefinition};
   listItem.RoleAssignments.Add(principal, roleBindings);
   ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

**Example**

The following example demonstrates how to grant `Read` permissions to every user (we use security group called `Everyone` in SPO for that purpose)

```
using(var ctx = new ClientContext(webUrl))
{     
   ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName,securePassword);

   var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
   var listItem = list.GetItemById(listItemId);             //get Folder item by Id
   var everyoneSecGroup = ctx.Web.SiteUsers.GetById(4);     //get Everyone security group            
   ShareListItem(listItem,everyoneSecGroup, "Read");
}
```

**Result**

[image]

**Update**

How to enumerate role definitions  and print permission name:

```
var roleDefinitions = ctx.Site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions;
ctx.Load(roleDefinitions);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var roleDef in roleDefinitions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(roleDef.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you

But when i execute the script i have an error on "Impossible de trouver le niveau d'autorisation." that mean unable to find the autorisation level"
the trouble is on this line
 var roleDefinition = ctx.Site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByName(permissionLevelName);

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Please make sure the proper permission name is specified, see the update section of answer for a details.

Comment: The permission name is localized it is effectively necessary to identify the right one.
thank you !